# How to add "open in terminal" in 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, command-line, nautilus, nautilus-actions

I had "open in terminal" in my previous ubuntu of 14.04 and it was a life safer, I can open terminal at a specific location and path. In ubuntu 16.04 also I want some thing like that so I followed [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/930679/158636) and installed `nautilus-actions`. The problem with this is that it will work only inside a nautilus and not work in desktop. Is there a light weight software which can be used to "Open  terminal here" in both the desktop and nautilus?

EDIT:

I somehow missed "open in terminal" in my nautilus window. It seems  that ubuntu 16.04 has built in "open in terminal" for nautilus. But my problem still exists. I cant open "open in terminal" from desktop.

Comment: This feature exist in 16.04 and you do not need `nautilus-actions`. Maybe during the upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04 something is went wrong. Have you tried to reinstall Nautilus?

Comment: Sorry yes its there. I some  how miss that but still its not available in desktop only in nautilus. Thank you

Comment: Indeed it does not work for the desktop. I VTC 'ed to the linked dupe. Please mention if you manage.

Answer (score 0):

This has moved to Gnome-Terminal package. Please uninstall it and install. Open xterm and run below commands.

```
sudo apt-get purge gnome-terminal
sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal
```

Restart the computer.

Comment: There is no such package for 16.04: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=nautilus-open-terminal

Comment: I thought this question is on older version thanks a lot for pointing it out