# Can't open nautilus-actions in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: nautilus, nautilus-actions

I just wanted to add 'Open in Terminal' right-click option for Nautilus. [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/930643/nautilus-where-is-the-open-in-terminal-option-ubuntu-16-10-nautilus-3-20-3) shows how.
After installing nautilus-actions when I'm trying to open it, I get this error:

```
bash: nautilus-actions-config-tool: command not found
```

(Check [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggwom.png))

Why? How can I open it. I couldn't find it via search in apps either (Gnome).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use FileManager Actions instead. This package is a replacement for  [`nautilus-actions`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/nautilus-actions) package.

Their configuration executable is named `fma-config-tool`.

---

Useful stuff to read is [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1257070/66509).